# Django Rest Framework: Custom IsReadOnly Permission

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I create a custom permission  which authorizes GET, HEAD and OPTION for everyone and which authorizes **NO** other requests.

But my code doesn't work. I can make a POST request despite my permission ...

Anyone have a idea to solve my problem ?

My `views.py`:

```
class IsReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return False

class ViewPollViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        IsReadOnly,
    ]
    serializer_class = ViewPollSerializer
    queryset = ViewPoll.objects.all()
```

My `serializers.py`:

```
class ViewPollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ViewPoll
        fields = '__all__'
```

My `models.py`:

```
class ViewPoll(models.Model):
    ''' view poll '''
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('poll', 'user')

    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="views", null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="views_poll", null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.poll.question)[:30]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call **`has_permission(...)`** method instead of `has_object_permission(...)` method

```
class IsReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return False
```